# thymeleaf passing a parameter from a form to a controller using a post

Tags: spring, forms, post, thymeleaf

Im making an app where i have users and some of them have a role Mentor. Users can choose a mentor, who will in time add a personal program and food regime for the user. So far  I am printing all the users, having the Mentor role in an html file, but i cant seem to pass the parameter (the current userID) in the post method to the controller.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.persistence.*;
 
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
     
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
     
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 45)
    private String email;
     
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 45)
    private String username;
     
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 64)
    private String password;
     
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String firstName;
     
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "age", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private int age;
    
    @Column(name = "sex")
    private String sex;
    
    @Column(name = "mentor_id", nullable = true)
    private Long mentorid;
    
    

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="account_id")
    private accountInfo accountinfo;
    public User() {}
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Blog> blogs= new ArrayList<Blog>();
    
    @ManyToOne(optional = false,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="role_id")    
    private UserRole role;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private PersonalProgram personalprogram;
   
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public accountInfo getAccountinfo() {
        return accountinfo;
    }
    public void setAccountinfo(accountInfo accountinfo) {
        this.accountinfo = accountinfo;
    }

    public List<Blog> getBlogs() {
        return blogs;
    }

    public void setBlogs(List<Blog> blogs) {
        this.blogs = blogs;
    }

    public UserRole getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(UserRole role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public Optional<Long> getMentorid() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(mentorid);
    }

    public void setMentorid(Long mentorid) {
        this.mentorid = mentorid;
    }

    public PersonalProgram getPersonalprogram() {
        return personalprogram;
    }

    public void setPersonalprogram(PersonalProgram personalprogram) {
        this.personalprogram = personalprogram;
    }

    
    
}
```

this is my user class

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>List of Trainers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function getUser(userid) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/trainers/choose?userId="+userid,
            type: "get",
            
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">
    
    <div>
        <h1>List of Trainers</h1>
    </div>
     
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="user,index: ${listUsers}"> ///i print each user from the list User
                    <td  th:text="${user.firstName}">First Name</td>
                    <td th:text="${user.lastName}">Last Name</td>
                    <td th:text="${user.age}">Age</td>
                    <td th:text="${user.email}">Email</td>
                    <td>
                    
                    
                        
                             <form th:action="@{/trainers/choose}"  th:object="${user}" method="post"> //Im trying to pass the id of the user on this row
                                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
                                <button type="submit">Choose</button> 
                            </form>
                                                         
                             
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my html

and i guess the controllers handler about the post Method going to look something like this

```
 @RequestMapping(value="trainers/choose", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String processTrainersChoose (@RequestParam Long mentorid) {
```

and the get method for visualising the html page is

````
@GetMapping("/trainers")
    public String listTrainers(Model model) {
        List<User> listUsers = userRepo.findAllByRole(userRoleRepo.findByName("ROLE_MENTOR"));
        model.addAttribute("listUsers", listUsers); 
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        
         
        return "trainers";
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Try to put your ENTIRE <table> inside the <form> tags. If it works then try to dig/google why it worked. :-)

Comment: nope :D I came to the idea i have to add a plain User new user in order for the model User and id to work but still cant manage return an Id of a user

```
@GetMapping("/trainers")
    public String listTrainers(Model model) {
     List<User> listUsers = userRepo.findAllByRole(userRoleRepo.findByName("ROLE_MENTOR"));
        model.addAttribute("listUsers", listUsers);
      //  model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        
         
        return "trainers";
    }
```

Comment: Try my above comment and also I dont see a form object in your form. Something like -    th:object="${user}". This can give you an idea - https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringCMS/blob/main/src/main/resources/templates/registration.html